# Missing data - different IP error when submitting a form

Tags: forms

Has anyone ever come across this error before? I've never seen it.

When a form is submitted, users get the error shown in the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Nit seen this before but is your ISP switching IP's randomly?

Comment: Could be, as I'm on a dynamic IP but its never happened before. I've used a dynamic IP address for around 12 years. I've submitted forms on this project for nearly 2 years and never seen this error. Developing for EE for nearly 5 years and never seen this error. Very very weird!

Comment: I'm having exactly this issue and the internet doesn't seem to be very helpful. Did you resolve it?

Comment: Nope, no solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spitballing here, but some sort of misconfigured proxy is the first thing that jumps out at me.

Comment: Or perhaps some kind of attempted Man In The Middle attack

Answer (score 3):

OK, I found a quick fix / workaround for this.

What the Forms Module looks to be doing is checking the IP address of where the form data is coming from, to the IP address that the form thinks it is.

system/expressionengine/third_party/forms/act.forms.php

And at around line 82 you should see:

```
    // Same IP?
    if ($this->EE->forms->data['ip_address'] != $this->EE->forms->ip_address)
    {
        return $this->return_error('missing_data', $this->EE->lang->line('form:error:missing_data') . '(DIFFERENT_IP)');
    }
```

I commented out these lines and it's working again. Why it started to do this I've no idea, the External IP has not changed, I've cleared the cache, I've rebooted the server, still no luck.

FINAL EDIT : We have a load balancing server. The IP address that the web server sees for that server is obviously different to the external IP address the visitor comes in on. Two different IP addresses. Why it just started happening now is still a mystery.

Comment: this worked for me - weird but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that , same thing happened to me when I turned on cloudflare cdn for my site. I did it via Cname so it changed my visible ip and caused the problem with all of my forms. Commenting those lines sorted it out for me. I am going to submit a ticket to devdemon to see if they have a more structured solution